# Constructor Overloading Issue in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, constructor-overloading

```
// Create a function which takes 2 point objects and computes the distance between those points
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

class dist{
    int x, y;    
public:
    dist(int a , int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
    dist();
    void caldistance(dist c1, dist c2) {
        // c1 = (8,9) & c2 (10, 7)
        // sqrt((10-8)^2 + (7-9)^2)
        // sqrt((c2.a-c1.a)^2 + (c2.b-c1.b)^2)
        int res = sqrt(pow((c2.x-c1.x),2)+pow((c2.y-c1.y),2));
        cout << "The Distance between the points ( " << c1.x << "," << c1.y << ")"  << "("<< c2.x << "," << c2.y << ")" << " is : " << res << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    dist P(8,9);
    dist Q(11,6);
    dist G;
    G.caldistance(P,Q);
    
    return 0;
}
```

As soon as I am creating a new object G of class dist, according to me, it should call the function call distance of class dist but it is showing an error and the program is not getting executed

Error : /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc99m1Ky.o: in function `main': try.cpp:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to` dist::dist()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: It's because you have declared, but not defined the default constructor. Consider, though, to make the function that calculates the distance a free function accepting two "points" and returning a floating point value that can later be printed.

Comment: I see no need for `caldistance` to be a member function, other than to access the private variables. That could be solved with making the function a `friend` of the class.

Comment: That could be done, but I just wanted to try how it can be done with constructors in this way. My aim is  not to solve this problem but to learn the use of constructors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the constructor as

```cpp
        dist():x(0),y(0) {}
```

`dist()` is just a declaration, but you have not defined the construtor.

Comment: `dist(){}` -- That leaves `x` and `y` uninitialized.  This code will go crazy: `dist d1; dist d2; dist G; G.calculate(d1, d2);`

Comment: There is no need for semicolon after `}`.

Comment: Thanks It worked, Finally i know how to tackle the default constructors

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie to initialize `x` and `y`, a separate constructor is defined

Comment: @DeepakGouda Did you see my example in the comment?  What is the distance between uninitialized and uninitialized?  A simple `dist() : x(0), y(0) { }` could have sufficed.  All constructors should initialize the members to some value, not just leave them there uninitialized, and thus abused, as in the example I gave.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In this question, the author intends on initialization via constructor for objects d1 and d2. Hence, I did not assign any default values inside the constructor. I agree, it is a good practice to have some default values. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Please note that many lint and source code checking tools will flag that constructor as a code smell without initializing all members, even though it is legal.   If those members were `double`, then it wouldn't be just "good practice" -- it would be mandatory to initialize the variables, since accessing uninitialized `doubles` invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've defined constructor that takes two `int`s, the compiler won't synthesize the default constructor for you, so it would be better to define the default constructor as a user-defined default constructor (no initialization list). As in `dist() = default;`

Though, note that members of built-in types won't have initial value in this case. So, it is considered a better practice to supply initial values for data members of built-in types in default constructor.
Like so:

```
dist(int val_x = 0, int val_y = 0) : x(val_x), y(val_y) {}
```

This constructor will handle both cases.